# Need a word for "situation where something was ignored"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for "situations where something was ignored"

Examples:

This was one of the worst ____ of democracy in history

His many ____ of basic hygiene led to his sickness

I was thinking "negligences" but that's not a real word. Something like that.

Comment: Neglect (noun) - the state of being uncared for.
"the place had a hopeless air of neglect"

Comment: Hmmm...oversights.  Look it up.

Comment: Why do you think that "neglicence" is not a real word? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/negligence It does not imply ignoring but giving insufficient attention but I think that it fits your needs.

Comment: I like "neglect," too, but it's a noncount noun, so you have to phrase it like, "one of the worst incidences of neglect"  or "his frequent neglect of basic hygiene."  If you don't like "neglect," you might go with "dereliction," which means the shameful failure to fulfill one's obligations.  You often hear the word "dereliction" in the phrase "dereliction of duty."

Comment: The two examples do not seem to need the same word or expression.

Comment: @RubioRic OP does not say that  "negligence" (which I assume you mean) is not a real word. They say that "negligences" is not a real word. And the dictionary you cite agrees, labelling "negligence" as non-count (U).

Comment: @Kris Agreed. In fact, I'd use 'This was one of the worst cases of democracy turning a blind eye in history' and 'His constant disregard for basic hygiene led to his sickness'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry my mistake, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word ***"dereliction"*** should work in your context.

## Dereliction

> (noun)
>
> 3a: intentional or conscious neglect.

([Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dereliction))

Therefore -

> *This was one of the worst **derelictions** of democracy in history.*
>
> *His many **derelictions** of basic hygiene led to his sickness*

Answer (score 2):

You could use lapse, or lapses. A lapse of judgement for example.

Merrian-Webster defines **lapse** as (intransitive verb):

: to fall from an attained and usually high level (as of morals or manners) to one much lower

: to depart from an accepted pattern or standard

Comment: Good suggestion. Please include a definition from a dictionary, for people who aren't sure what the word means.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @marcellothearcane

Answer (score 0):

Try Nescience.

Merriam-Webster definition for this noun is:
lack of knowledge or awareness.